# Horizontal spacing with HTML/CSS within parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to space elements throughout my webpage that are contained within a `<div class="card">` from a template I am using. I have been trying to use inline CSS to space elements, as I am new to HTML/CSS and the CSS file from the template is difficult for me to navigate (and understand).

Inline CSS overrides the CSS files contained in the directory, as far as I understand. My elements looks like:
[image: pic1]

And I would like them to be spaced like:
[image: pic2]

My code looks like:

```
<div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card ">
                            <div class="card-body">

                            <select class="custom-select">
                                <option selected>Zero</option>
                                <option value="1">One</option>
                                <option value="2">Two</option>
                                <option value="3">Three</option>
                            </select>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="comment">Input:</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="comment"></textarea>
                                </div>

                                <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 48px;">arrow_forward</i>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="comment">Output:</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="comment"></textarea>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>
```

I have tried a number of methods to get this to work, and nothing has worked particularly well for me. My question is, how can I achieve the spacing I laid out in the second picture?

Comment: You do not need to use inline css to override other css. You simply need to load the "overrides" after the original css and use the same (or more specific) selectors to set the styles.

Answer (score 1):

You said you wanted inline css, so I did inline css.

1. We are doing `display:inline-block` so that we can keep our divs on the same row, `float-left` so they are positioned as far left as possible without colliding with other elements.
2. On class *custom-select* we also set the position to `relative` which enables us to do `top:35px` which moves that element down 35 pixels. I did that because that's sort of how it appears in your image.
3. Finally the use of `!important` will override ANY css usually unless !important is declared elsewhere, then you may still have a conflict. I highly doubt it's declared elsewhere however as there is no real point to doing it unless you want to override a previous setting.

```html
<div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card ">
                            <div class="card-body">

                            <select class="custom-select" style="display:inline-block !important;float:left !important;position:relative;top:35px">
                                <option selected>Zero</option>
                                <option value="1">One</option>
                                <option value="2">Two</option>
                                <option value="3">Three</option>
                            </select>
                                <div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block !important;float:left !important">
                                    <label for="comment">Input:</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="comment"></textarea>
                                </div>

                                <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 48px;display:inline-block !important;float:left !important">-&#8250;</i>


                                <div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block !important;float:left !important">
                                    <label for="comment">Output:</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="comment"></textarea>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/hw2tv6g1/

Comment: It looks nearly perfect on JSFIDDLE, but on my webpage it does not come out correctly, in fact very strangely the values in the `select` box appear to be detached from the select box and are sitting outside of it now. Also the form-groups are still quite small.

Comment: Also, perhaps update your question with the code that you are having issues with the select box from. When I copy pasted from jsfiddle earlier I had copy paste issues so it's possible that we are missing an HTML tag somewhere if you had issues too. Are you missing the </select> tag perhaps?

Comment: Getting closer, now everything is oriented correctly (as in everything is lined up horizontally), but they are all bunched together and still attached to the very left of the parent element. Sort of like my original screenshot, but horizontal instead of vertical now. Also, to be clear, this card is nested in another div, which may be what is causing the problem but I'm not sure. Also, I am using bootstrap. And to your extra tag point, I believe there was an extra div related to a higher div on the page.

Comment: Perhaps try this on your card-body class. `<div class="card-body" style="margin-left:25px !important;">` Just for info on `margin` css... you can do margin-left, margin-right, margin-top, margin-bottom, or just margin by itself for all sides. This will allow you to space it a little in any direction.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help. That helped marginally (it moved the elements slightly to the right), but still not like how it appears in jsfiddle. The elements are still like I mentioned before (my original screenshot, but horizontal instead of vertical now). Unfortunately all of the HTML tutorials out there just focus on describing different types of elements, instead of the intricacies of spacing. I am using a template such as: https://demos.creative-tim.com/light-bootstrap-dashboard-pro/examples/dashboard.html if that helps you get a sense for the larger scope. Thanks again.

Comment: The "card" I am using is the larger one with the "map" on it in that link after having removed the other "cards".

Answer (score 1):

That's the CSS I applied to your html.

```
.card-body > select {
  vertical-align: top;
  }
.card-body > div {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

[Demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/xa3cg8pe/)

Comment: This worked somewhat well, but for some reason the select element's values are detached from it and are resting on the outside, also the other three elements are oriented correctly but still stuck to the left edge of the parent element with the detached select element above also still stuck to the left of the parent card element.

Comment: I guess the reason for this is that you probably have additional styles (like bootstrap or etc) on your webpage and they make the difference.

Comment: I do have bootstrap, yes. I was hoping that the locally declared CSS could override that?

Comment: Yes you can override it, but you need to change the exact css properties. I need to check more of your code, so I could tell you where is the problem.

Comment: I am using this template: https://demos.creative-tim.com/light-bootstrap-dashboard-pro/examples/dashboard.html I have only removed all the other "cards" and am now just using the the large card with the map in it.